# Algorithms for computing $(I + \frac{Q}{n})^n$

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I need to compute the matrix $(I + \frac{Q}{n})^n$ where $n = 2^k$, $k$ is integer. I want to know if there is any practical and effective algorithms.

Comment: For $n$ large, this expression limits to the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential). Most methods to compute the matrix exponential are ["bad" in some sense, though some worse than others](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf).

Comment: To the OP. You asked a question. The least you can do, is read the answers and give your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q\in M_m$. If you want a result for only one large $n$, then use the Hyperplane's method (the complexity is $k$ matrix mult,  that is,  $km^3$ mult-add. on the entries).

If you want results for $p$ values of large $n$, then diagonalize $Q$ (if possible) $Q=Pdiag(\lambda_i)P^{-1}$ (complexity $\approx 40m^3$). Then, for each $n$, $(I+Q/n)^n=Pdiag((1+\lambda_i/n)^n)P^{-1}$; that is, a total complexity $(40+p)m^3$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response since I am busy with another topic. Your answer is quite helpful and a good start for me to study related algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the green ticket.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x^{16} = (x^8)^2 = ((x^4)^2)^2 = (((x^2)^2)^2)^2 $$